# vector component form from symmetric equation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

I'm working through some practice problems in one of my math textbooks, and I'm told to find both the parametric and symmetric equations of the line through $(1,-1,1)$ and parallel to the line $ x + 2 = \frac{y}{2} = z-3 $.

I am trying to find the component form of the vector described by $ x + 2 = \frac{y}{2} = z-3 $, (i.e. in the form $<x_{0},\, y_{0},\, z_{0}>$).

My thought was that I could reverse the process of getting to the symmetric equation by taking the denominators of each of those terms  - would I be correct in saying that $ x + 2 = \frac{y}{2} = z-3 $ is the symmetric equation describing the line $r = (-2,0,3) + t<\!1,2,1\!>$  which has the parametric equations $x=-2+t;\,\,y=2t;\,\, z=3+t$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is correct. In general, the line $\mathbf{r}(t) = (x_0,y_0,z_0) + t\,(a,b,c)$ is equivalent to the symmetric equation
$$\frac{x-x_0}{a} = \frac{y-y_0}{b} = \frac{z-z_0}{c}.$$

Comment: Awesome, I just don't trust my intuition at times. I'll vote up when I have the reputation to allow me to do so.